unexpected behavior in .htaccess when redirecting directory paths to a .php script
I'm working on a website template.
The idea is to have the following base directory structure:
template     // template-only files, don't modify!
  private    // for internal usage
  public     // for public output
customizable // template-provided, but customizable files
  private    // for internal usage
  public     // for public output
custom       // fully custom files
  private    // for internal usage
  public     // for public output

The idea is that when a user tries to access a certain path, the following processing takes place:

remove trailing slashes (they seem to mess with the way paths are handled, even when starting paths with "/")
if a file exists at one of the following paths, output that file: template/public/<RequestPath>, customizable/public/<RequestPath> or custom/public/<RequestPath>
otherwise (if the path is a directory or is not within one of the public subdirectories, call a .php script with that given path as a parameter.

I already wrote the following, and it already works for 99% of the cases:
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing "/" from requests
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /[^/]+/\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]



# for existing files within one of the "public" directories,
# internally redirect to that file.

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/template/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /template/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/customizable/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /customizable/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/custom/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /custom/public/$1 [L]



# redirect any remaining requests to virtualpath.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(template|customizable|custom)/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /template/private/virtualpath.php?path=%1 [L,QSA]


The only issue is the behaviour of the server when requesting one of the actual directories directly: /custom and /custom/ turn into /custom/?path=custom; same with the other directories - /template/public turns into /template/public/?path=template/public, etc.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I did my research, tried tons of solutions from the internet and got way too frustrated over ChatGPT not being helpful at all.
So: Does anybody here have an idea what I can do?
I don't think it's relevant, but I'm using XAMPP for testing.
I tried to debug the redirection by setting LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8 – here's the resulting log text from error.log:
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template -> template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'template'
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template -> template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/public/template' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template -> template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/customizable/public/template' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template -> template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/custom/public/template' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template -> template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'template'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='/template' pattern='!^/(template|customizable|custom)/public/' => matched
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template' pattern='!-f' => matched
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='GET /template HTTP/1.1' pattern='^[A-Z]{3,9}\\ /(.*)\\ HTTP/' [NC] => matched
[...] [rewrite:trace2] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] rewrite 'template' -> '/template/private/virtualpath.php?path=template'
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] split uri=/template/private/virtualpath.php?path=template -> uri=/template/private/virtualpath.php, args=path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace2] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] trying to replace context docroot D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs with context prefix 
[...] [rewrite:trace1] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] internal redirect with /template/private/virtualpath.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/ -> template/
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'template/'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='GET /template/?path=template HTTP/1.1' pattern='^[A-Z]{3,9}\\ /[^/]+/\\ HTTP/' [NC] => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/ -> template/
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/public/template/' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/ -> template/
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/customizable/public/template/' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/ -> template/
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/custom/public/template/' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/ -> template/
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'template/'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='/template/' pattern='!^/(template|customizable|custom)/public/' => matched
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/' pattern='!-f' => matched
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='GET /template/?path=template HTTP/1.1' pattern='^[A-Z]{3,9}\\ /(.*)\\ HTTP/' [NC] => matched
[...] [rewrite:trace2] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] rewrite 'template/' -> '/template/private/virtualpath.php?path=template/'
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] split uri=/template/private/virtualpath.php?path=template/ -> uri=/template/private/virtualpath.php, args=path=template/&path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace2] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] trying to replace context docroot D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs with context prefix 
[...] [rewrite:trace1] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] internal redirect with /template/private/virtualpath.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php'
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/public/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/customizable/public/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/custom/public/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] RewriteCond: input='/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='!^/(template|customizable|custom)/public/' => matched
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php'
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] RewriteCond: input='GET /template/?path=template HTTP/1.1' pattern='^[A-Z]{3,9}\\ /(template|customizable|custom)\\b\\ HTTP/' [NC] => not-matched
[...] [rewrite:trace1] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][rid#169ac128470/initial/redir#1] [...] pass through D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'favicon.ico', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'favicon.ico', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'favicon.ico', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/customizable/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'favicon.ico', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/custom/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'favicon.ico', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='/favicon.ico' pattern='!^/(template|customizable|custom)/public/' => matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/favicon.ico' pattern='!-f' => matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1' pattern='^[A-Z]{3,9}\\ /(.*)\\ HTTP/' [NC] => matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace2] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] rewrite 'favicon.ico' -> '/template/private/virtualpath.php?path=favicon.ico', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] split uri=/template/private/virtualpath.php?path=favicon.ico -> uri=/template/private/virtualpath.php, args=path=favicon.ico, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace2] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] trying to replace context docroot D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs with context prefix , referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace1] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] internal redirect with /template/private/virtualpath.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT], referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/public/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/customizable/public/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/custom/public/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='!^/(template|customizable|custom)/public/' => matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php -> template/private/virtualpath.php, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace3] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'template/private/virtualpath.php', referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace4] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] RewriteCond: input='GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1' pattern='^[A-Z]{3,9}\\ /(template|customizable|custom)\\b\\ HTTP/' [NC] => not-matched, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template
[...] [rewrite:trace1] [...] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client <...>] 127.0.0.1 - - [...][...] [...] pass through D:/Programme/XAMPP/htdocs/template/private/virtualpath.php, referer: http://localhost/template/?path=template


I suggest you enable rewrite logging inside your http server. See the documentation on that. It allows to understand what exactly is going on inside your request engine on a step by step base.

Just did that, it just directly switches from /template to /template/?path=template.

That is pretty little information. What level did you set? Could you please add the lines from the log to the question? Thanks!

Here you go, I added the information you asked about.

No, that is just the access log. You need to enable rewrite logging . That is something different. Take a look at the explanation atop https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

I suppose now it's correct? I had to remove some parts though; I wanted to include all the seemingly relevant lines but hit SO's character limit.

OK, that is a rewrite log now, indeed. However it is pretty hard to reed, it apparently contains many requests, not one that is singled out. As far as I could interpret that log it looks to me like requests to /template are rewritten to /template/private/virtualpath.php?path=template, the same with trailing slash. That looks fine to me. I do not see any redirection from /template to /template?path=/template, but instead requests to that URL. Which implies that the redirecting is not the result of the rewriting process, but maybe of what virtualpath.php outputs ...

Please reduce that log to a single, isolated requests (the difference of the log bevor and after making a single request to /template. Not more. And also add the exact responses you receive back from the server. You can see those in your browser's development console, inside the "network" tab in there.

all virtualpath.php does is output the current path variable to the screen.

The log shows a single "request" (call in the browser), actually. I cleared the log file, started the server and opened /template in my browser. That's it. The 1st "..." is the timestamp, and it was all exactly the same.

OK, I recreated your setup to have a look. Looks like you have mod_dir enabled inside your http server? If so have a try disabling it's trailing slash automatism with DirectorySlash Off somewhere in the host configuration.

I just use the default XAMPP configuration; I don't ususally mess around with the server settings. But anyways, I already tried using DirectorySlash Off before - I tried again for you, I put it at the top of the .htaccess, but that just leads to the site breaking entirely (directories give an error 500 and anything else gives a 404).

OK, that is surprising. Though I would always recommend to prefer the central configuration over using distributed configuration files (typically called ".htaccess", coming with quite some disadvantages) this should work. If it breaks your site then it would be important to find the reason. The status 500 the server answers to clients does not contain that information for privacy reasons. In such a case you should look into your http server's error log file. That is where the reason for the status 500 is logged.

I suggest that change since I was able to reproduce your rewriting log output and also the rewriting response you showed here. That was resolved with above directive in my setup.

Unfortunately I don't have full access to the server. My plan includes FTP + SSH access, but I can't access the actual server root etc. My view is very limited. E.g., I can't set up subdomains or DNS in a file either, I have to do so via a web interface. So I don't know if anything but the distributed configuration is available to me.

OK, I understand. I thought it was a server you controlled yourself because you mentioned XAMPP above. Which is something people use to setup a service themselves, not something a provider would use. As said: the status 550 is something that will definitely leave an entry in the http server's error log file. And you certainly will have some mean to look into that. So what exactly is causing the status 500 if you use the directive?
